# perl - usage of $ symbol

Tags: perl, hash, syntax

I know `$`, `@` and `%` are for declaring scalars, arrays and hashes. But I am confused when when `$` is used in declaration of other things like

```
my %myhash1 = ( a => 1,  b => 2 );
my $myhash2 = { A => 27, B => 27};
```

and usage of following syntax

```
%myhash1
%$myhash2
```

Can someone please explain me the difference and when to use them.

Comment: While questions like this are an important part of learning, they're also off-topic on Stack Overflow. Take some time to read through an [introduction to Perl](https://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/) which covers the various symbols used and when to use them. Look for more information on [references](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Comment: `my %myhash1 = { a => 1,  b => 2 };` does not do anything useful (and indeed `use warnings;` will complain about it).

Comment: See also https://perldoc.pl/perlreftut.

Comment: `%hash` is a hash variable, `$hash` is a scalar variable, you can assign a reference to a scalar variable. For example `$hash = { a => 1 }` assigns it a reference to a hash. When you need to treat a scalar reference as a hash you can put a `%` in front, i.e. `%$hash` will be a hash variable

Answer (score 3):

No, the sigils refer to the mode of access. `$` means a single element, `@` means multiple elements and `%` means key/value pairs. Demo:

#### no references involved

```
$myhash1{a}             # 1
@myhash1{qw(a b)}       # (1, 2)
%myhash1{a}             # (a => 1)
```

#### with references involved

```
$$myhash2{A}            # 27
@$myhash2{qw(A B)}      # (27, 27)
%$myhash2{A}            # (A => 27)
```

which is just short-hand for

```
${ $myhash2 }{A}        # 27
@{ $myhash2 }{qw(A B)}  # (27, 27)
%{ $myhash2 }{A}        # (A => 27)
```

which is much more clearly written using the `->` deref operator

```
$myhash2->{A}           # 27
$myhash2->@{qw(A B)}    # (27, 27)
$myhash2->%{A}          # (A => 27)
```

Prefer the notation shown in the last block.

---

Lack of subscripting braces:

- `%myhash1` means: all k/v pairs in the hash.
- Any of `%$myhash2`, `%{ $myhash2 }`, `$myhash2->%*` means: all k/v pairs in the dereferenced hash.

Answer (score 1):

Perl 5 *sigils* (the $, @, and %) can be confusing. Here's a condensed explanation. (The Perl 6 rules are different and I'm skipping them here, and as @ikegami notes, there are some other features, like hash and array slices, that I'm also skipping for concision.)

A *dollar sign* sigil *always* means "I am dealing with a scalar value". So the variable `$foo` is a variable containing a single scalar value (there are cases as noted where a scalars actually contains multiple different things that are accessed in different contexts, but this is not important for what we're interested in right now).

This is true when you're accessing array and hash elements: `$foo[0]` says "I am accessing the *scalar value* found in element `0` of the array `@foo`. For a hash, `$foo{'bar'}` says "I am accessing the *scalar value* found in the element whose key is `bar` in the hash `%foo`.

An *at-sign* sigil denotes an array *as a whole*. `@foo` means "all of the array whose name is `foo`". (Skipping slices here; they're a way to get a list of things out of a hash or array at once. Really useful, but they'll obscure our point right now.)

Similarly, a *percent sign* denotes a hash *as a whole*. `%foo` is the hash named `foo` -- all of it at once. (Same for hash slices.)

These are all the base data types in Perl: scalars (`$`), arrays (`@`), and hashes (`%`). There's also the `sub` (`&` - function) type, which we'll talk more about below, and globs (`*` - which are beyond the scope of this answer, so we'll skip them too).

If we want more complex, nested data structures, we now have to move on to *references*.

A reference is, to wildly oversimplify, essentially a pointer that knows the kind of thing it points to. References are *always* scalars. If we want a reference to something, there are, as one would expect in Perl 5, several ways to get one:

- Use the *backslash* (`\`) operator to specifically get a reference. We can do this with any of the three types of variables (scalar, hash, array) and with subroutines as well (remember, subroutines have a sigil of `&`). This is the only way to get a reference to a scalar variable.
- Use one of the *anonymous constructors* to build a reference to a hash or array.
- Construct a subroutine (function) reference in-line with an anonymous subroutine.

Here's examples of each:

```
# Define a reference to a scalar
$foo = \$bar;

# Define a reference to an array, a hash and an existing subroutine:
$x = \@w;
$y = \%zorch;
$z = \&do_stuff;

# define anonymous arrays, hashes, and subs:
$my_array = [2, 3, 'fred', 'hoplite'];
$my_hash  = {foo => 'bar', baz => 'quux'};
$pi_sub   = sub { return 3.14 };
```

There are *three* different ways to "dereference" (follow the pointer in) a reference.

1. Use *stacked* sigils. These read from right to left; each sigil dereferences the variable again. This is most often used to dereference a scalar. You'll usually only see two, but sometimes multiple levels of dereferencing are done at once to go through a chain of scalar values. Stacked sigils can be confusing, mostly because they add a right-to-left interpretation to a language that is read primarily left-to-right.
2. Use a sigil and *paired braces*. This is the logical equivalent of using parens to disambiguate expressions. What's inside the braces is dereferenced as the type outside the braces. Most often used to get aggregate types from a reference.
3. Use a chained series of dereference operators. Each dereference implies that the lefthand side is a scalar reference, so several in a row implies that the result of each dereference is another (scalar) reference. Handy for digging down into a structure to find something.

Here are examples:

```
# Dereference a scalar using stacked sigils.
print $$foo; # $foo is a reference to the scalar $bar
             # the second $ says "please give me the value of the scalar
             $ I now have" (in this case that's $bar).

# Use braces and sigils to dereference a scalar, getting a hash/array
%hash = ( a => 1, b => 2);
my %thing = %{ $my_hash }; # dereference the scalar
                           # copy the resulting hash into %thing

# Chained dereferences
# A hash of hashes:
$sample = { one => { a => 1, b => 2}, two => { aa => 4, bb => 8 }};
# To get to 8, we need to dereference twice:
$eight = $sample->{two}->{bb};

# Note that we can collapse the chain after the first deref.
$same_result = $sample->{two}{bb}

# If we wanted to get an element from $my_hash, we don't have to
# dereference it and construct the new hash. We can just use the 
# dereference operator.
$x = $my_hash->{a} == $thing{a}; # $x is 1 (true).
```

Any combination of nestings is permitted, so we could have a hash of arrays of hashes of subs, for instance.

Subs are a special case in that all we can do with them is copy their references, or call them:

```
$pi_times = sub { my $x = shift; return 3.14159 * $x };
$the_sub  = $pi_times;
$z = $the_sub->(4);  # calls the $pi_times anonymous sub
                     # returns pi * 4
```

The `perldoc perlre` man page goes into this in detail; `perldoc perlreftut` is a good tutorial which follows up what I've outlined here in a lot more detail.

Comment: [Nit] Re "*So the variable $foo is a variable containing a single scalar value.*", Usually. (Or rather, they often contain multiple scalar values, but they are equivalent such as the stringification of the number within, so you can't tell.) Notable exceptions include the builtin value used for false (`!!0`) and `$!`.

Comment: Re "*An at-sign sigil denotes an array as a whole.*", Not so. `@foo[...]` and `@foo{...}`

Comment: Re "*Similarly, a percent sign denotes a hash as a whole.*", Not so. `%foo{...}`.

Comment: Re "*There's also the sub (function) type, which we'll talk more about below.*", There are also globs (`*`). These aren't the only 5 types of variables in the symbol table, but the others  (file handle, dir handle, format, etc) don't have sigils associated with them, so one is therefore only able to access them indirectly.

Comment: Agreed about globs, but given the asker is having trouble with the basics, I decided to skip them for the purposes of this answer. And slices for the same reason. And multi-value scalars. The answer should be sufficient to get them past the basics of "what are all these sigils doing??".